# Javascript SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have the following simple code, however for some reason it trows a Unexpected token "}" error, and I'm not entirely sure why.
I have the following code to generate the buttons

```
var OverlayMessage = ("Do you want to test these settings? <br> <h6>" + protocol + ":" + systemcodeSend + "-" + unitcode + " sending " + state + '</h6> <br> <a id="btnGreen" onclick="checkIfSettingsWork("' + protocol +'", "'+ systemcodeSend +'", "'+ unitcode +'", "'+ state +'");">Yes</a> <a id="btnRed" onclick="toggleVisibility(\'overlayAddDevice\')">No</a>');
        console.log(OverlayMessage);
        overlayMessage(OverlayMessage);
```

The output of console.log is as followed

```
<a id="btnGreen" onclick="checkIfSettingsWork("pollin", "31", "14", "on");">Yes</a>
```

The strange thing is, if I run from the debugger, it works fine without errors. However when being ran trough the onclick event it trows the Unexpected token error.

The function checkIfSettingsWork is not even being ran, I checked this by letting it log to console, and that is returning nothing when being ran by the onclick event however it works when I run the following javascript trough the debugger.

```
checkIfSettingsWork("pollin", "31", "14", "on");
```

This is the checkIfSettingsWork function.

```
function checkIfSettingsWork(protocol, systemcodeSend, unitcode, state) {
    console.log(protocol + systemcodeSend + unitcode + state)

}
```

Comment: try replacing those double quotes in the parameters with single quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid html:

```
 <a id="btnGreen" onclick="checkIfSettingsWork("pollin", "31", "14", "on");">Yes</a>
```

The `"` characters are ending your `onclick` attribute early, so the browser ends up interpreting it as just `onclick="checkIfSettingsWork("`.

Change it to this for a workaround:

```
<a id="btnGreen" onclick="checkIfSettingsWork('pollin', '31', '14', 'on')">Yes</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The valid synatax will be

```
<a id="btnGreen" onclick="checkIfSettingsWork('pollin', '31', '14', 'on')">Yes</a>
```

Comment: Mmh does OP really need a TL;DR answer for barely 6 lines of text?

Answer (score 0):

You made a low-level mistake.

This is invalid like `onclick="checkIfSettingsWork("pollin", "31", "14", "on");"`

You need fix " to ' .

Another thing is i think when you declaring  `OverlayMessage`, just my suggestion, maybe you need use `"` and `'` characters by uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

You have many contexts going on here and I think they need to be separated. You are trying to create text, HTML, and JavaScript in this one declaration. Also in you mixed single and  double quotes.  In your concatenation.  You could use both but they have to match.

It's not safe to do all these  in one line. Especially the onClick function.  I don't want to create a template for the HTML, right out for a JavaScript function, then feed the variables into the function.

You also don't need any quotes for your parameters in your function you could just feed in the variables.

CheckIfSettingsWork( protocol, systemcodeSend, unitcode, state)